# Emit keydown event with key modifier on a stub in vue-test-utils

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils

I have a auto-stubbed child component with a keydown event with a `.down` modifier. I want to trigger this event in my test.

**Somewhere in component.vue:**

```
<child-component @keydown.down="myFn()" />
```

**Somewhere in component.spec.js:**

```
 // I expect the keydown.down event to be triggered:
 wrapper.find({name: 'child-component'}).vm.$emit('keydown.down')
```

This doesn't work. The only way I was able to trigger the event is when i remove the modifier `.down`, or if I add a `.native` modifier to the event. Unfortunately I'm  unable to use the `.native` modifier.

**Other things I've tried:**

`wrapper.find({name: 'child-component'}).trigger('keydown.down')`

`wrapper.find({name: 'child-component'}).vm.$emit('keydown', {keyCode: 40})`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to supply a `KeyboardEvent` as the second parameter of the `$emit` function, with the `keyCode` of the key modifier. So if we want to trigger a `keydown.down` event, we can do so as such:

```
wrapper.find({name: 'child-component'}).vm.$emit(
    'keydown', 
    new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
        keyCode: 40
    })
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing your finding ! I had tried many ways without success until reading your solution